Get the last child node and its associated namespace mapping dynamically in xml file using python
I have an xml file as below:
xml_s = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xml:base="https://url_path/1f3a6012-d6b2-4258-a91a-fc6d4e86c304/"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<title type="text">Data</title>
<id>https://<url_path>/1f3a6012-d6b2-4258-a91a-fc6d4e86c304/Data</id>
<updated>2024-07-18T05:22:18Z</updated>
<link rel="self" title="Data" href="Data" />
<m:count>5746</m:count>
<entry>
    <id>uuid:58aaa654-1649-4061-97fe-ecc53e186fee;id=1</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2024-07-18T05:22:18Z</updated>
    <category term="Intelex.Data" 
    scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
        <m:properties>
            <d:RowNum m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:RowNum>
            <d:Record_x0020_No m:type="Edm.Int64">491</d:Record_x0020_No>
            <d:Location m:type="Edm.String">Amine &gt; Shared</d:Location>
            <d:MOC_x0020_Initiator m:type="Edm.String" m:null="true" />
            <d:Status m:type="Edm.String">Vertical Heads Approval</d:Status>
            <d:Workflow_x0020_Status m:type="Edm.String">1</d:Workflow_x0020_Status>
            <d:Date_x0020_Created m:type="Edm.DateTime">2022-11-15T15:01:17</d:Date_x0020_Created>
        </m:properties>
    </content>
</entry>
<entry>
    <id>uuid:58aaa654-1649-4061-97fe-ecc53e186fee;id=2</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2024-07-18T05:22:18Z</updated>
    <category term="Intelex.Data" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
        <m:properties>
            <d:RowNum m:type="Edm.Int32">2</d:RowNum>
            <d:Record_x0020_No m:type="Edm.Int64">586</d:Record_x0020_No>
            <d:Location m:type="Edm.String">Ruby &gt; DNB-NT</d:Location>
            <d:MOC_x0020_Initiator m:type="Edm.String">XYZ</d:MOC_x0020_Initiator>
            <d:Status m:type="Edm.String">Vertical Heads Approval</d:Status>
            <d:Workflow_x0020_Status m:type="Edm.String">1</d:Workflow_x0020_Status>
            <d:Date_x0020_Created m:type="Edm.DateTime">2022-12-07T14:14:19</d:Date_x0020_Created>
        </m:properties>
    </content>
</entry>
</feed>
"""

I am trying to convert this in pandas dataframe using pd.read_xml().
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

x = ET.parse(xml_s)  
root = x.getroot()
s = ET.tostring(root).decode()

namespace = 
  {'ns_0': 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom',
   'ns_1': 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices',
   'ns_2': 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata'}

df = pd.read_xml(s,namespaces = namespace, xpath='.//properties')

But this is giving me an error.
ValueError: xpath does not return any nodes. Be sure row level nodes are in xpath. If 
document uses namespaces denoted with xmlns, be sure to define namespaces and use them 
in xpath.

Then I noticed that properties tag is mapped with m namespace. Hence I supplied xpath = './/ns_2:properties' and this has worked!!
So with that my question would be:

How can I dynamically identify the "last child node" of any xml. My assumption is that within the "last child node" the actual data would be present.
Since in this case the last child node was associated with m namespace, how this mapping can be done dynamically?



"last child" of which parent? Deepest node in the tree seems to be d:Date_x0020_Created 2. This xpath does not use namespaces //*[local-name()="properties"]


As you have discovered, the namespace-prefix that is used in the instance document and the namespace-prefix used by your XPath engine don't have to match. However, the namespace-uri of those namespaces must match. Think of the namespace-prefix like a variable name with the namespace-uri being assigned the same value. It's the value that matters when checking if they match and select the nodes bound to that namespace-uri.
You could use a predicate (square braces) with a condition that says the selected properties must not have any following properties elements.
//ns_2:properties[not(following::ns_2:properties)]

With XPath 2 or greater, you could wrap the selected properties in parens and use a predicate to select the last one from the sequence of selected properties elements:
(//ns_2:properties)[last()]


But how to identify whether properties is the last child node

With the XPath that I posted. You apply the predicate to ensure that it's only selecting the properties element that doesn't have any other properties elements following it.

So you meant in the pd.read_xml() I pass the xpath =//ns_2:properties[not(following::ns_2:properties)] ? Not sure how this would help.

Your posted xml is not valid! Error in Line7. You can use a validator. It’s enough, if you import pandas!
You get not such an error, if you use:
import pandas as pd

filename = “your_example.xml”
df = pd.read_xml(filename, xpath=".//m:properties", namespaces={'m': 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata'})
print(df)

I know this will not answer your question about the deepest level, but why could you be sure, that you always interested on the deepest level?

The reason I am trying to retrieve .//m:properties automatically so that the program can be used for all xml.
